# Appstore submission and giving permission for reviwers

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, appstore-approval

I  am planning to release my app for appstore submission . The app is dependent on a webportal to create user accounts and reset the user credentials. However the webportal is not finalized yet , therefore we can't expose it to the public. Is there anyway, we can find out the IP ranges used by the reviewers to give access to them to our webportal ?

So our external links will work properly.

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reviewers usually use 17.x.x.x addresses. Apple owns that full /8 block. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assigned_/8_IPv4_address_blocks.

I've also watched my own server logs during review and can verify that in every case I've looked, they have hit my servers from one of those addresses.